# MySQL group_concat and count

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join, group-concat

I am trying to get the aspects of each category in a single query as follows:

```
SELECT b.`id` AS parent_id, b.`name` AS parent_name, 
    a.`id` AS child_id, a.`name` AS child_name, a.`pageid` AS t_id, 
    COUNT( c.`id` ) AS deals_in_cat, 
    d.`aspect_values` AS aspects 
        FROM `category_parent` AS a 
        LEFT JOIN `navigation_filters_weightage` AS d ON a.`id` = d.`cat_id`, 
        `deals_parent_cat` AS b, 
        `deals` AS c 
    WHERE a.`parent_id` = b.`id` 
    AND c.`ebaydeals_category` = a.`id` 
        GROUP BY a.`id`, d.`frequency` 
        ORDER BY b.`order` ASC, a.`order` ASC, d.`frequency` DESC;
```

This query gives me the following result:

[image: PHPMyAdmin Result]

As you can see, all the aspects of a category (Mobiles, in this case) are in a separate row. What i want is to get all aspects of all categories in a single row. So, i try this query:

```
SELECT b.`id` AS parent_id, b.`name` AS parent_name, 
    a.`id` AS child_id, a.`name` AS child_name, a.`pageid` AS t_id, 
    COUNT( c.`id` ) AS deals_in_cat, 
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT d.`aspect_values` ORDER BY d.`frequency` DESC ) AS aspects 
        FROM `category_parent` AS a 
        LEFT JOIN `navigation_filters_weightage` AS d ON a.`id` = d.`cat_id`, 
        `deals_parent_cat` AS b, 
        `deals` AS c 
    WHERE a.`parent_id` = b.`id` 
    AND c.`ebaydeals_category` = a.`id` 
        GROUP BY a.`id` 
        ORDER BY b.`order` ASC , a.`order` ASC;
```

This gives the below result:

[image]

As you see, the `count` has increased for mobiles category. There are only 271 items for Mobiles, but the second query almost multiplies this number by the no. of aspects for that category.

I am not sure why is this happening. Any ideas would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you have repeated ids from table c try `count(DISTINCT c.id ) `

Comment: Oh! Such a slip! Thanks a lot @m-khalid-junaid! Could you post this as answer so that i could accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There may be repeated ids from table `deals` try using `DISTINCT`  in your count function

```
SELECT b.id AS parent_id, 
    b.name AS parent_name, 
    a.id AS child_id,
    a.name AS child_name, 
    a.pageid AS t_id, 
    count(DISTINCT c.id ) AS deals_in_cat ...
```

Comment: Thanks man for the quick solve! Was looking at the wrong columns for issues.

Comment: simplest and correct answer